# Directory of .htaccess get changed

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5

In my laravel project. I have changed the directory for htaccess file to root directory from public folder. Now asset() is not working properly on server to access the files. I think changes required in htaccess file.

I replace asset() with URL::asset() and url() but it is not working.

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

I want to use asset() to access files from public folder.

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` needs to be inside public/ not the root of the project. Actually public/ is root for the web, end-users.

Comment: Have you changed the default .htaccess from public/ ?

Comment: I moved index.php and .htaccess from public to root .. i didn;t changed anything else

Comment: are you there ?

Comment: index.php and .htacces must be in public/. Why is different topic.

Answer (score 0):

The root of your Laravel project **should not** be publicly visible.

I'm getting the impression that you have installed Laravel within a public folder on your server.  Is this what you have done?

```
/home/{user}/public_html/{your Laravel installation}
```

You would be better off moving the Laravel installation to it's own folder outside of public root.

```
/home/{user}/laravel/{your Laravel installation}
```

Then, you can remove the `public_html` folder and replace it with a symlink to your `laravel/public` folder.

```php
rmdir /home/{user}/public_html
ln -s /home/{user}/laravel/public /home/{user}/public_html
```

This will allow you to maintain the security of your application files.

Comment: problem is my server don't have public_html  folder . if it exist i could move my htaccess file and index.php file to that folder. now it is not present and i move my both files to root directory and my project is installed in the root directory also

Comment: It may not be called 'public_html` but you must have a public document root.

Comment: yes i have public folder. but when i move index.php and .htaccess file there server giver me 404 error

Comment: here is the url "public/http://qr.solutions-iv.com/js/app.js" 
it should be 
"http://qr.solutions-iv.com/js/app.js" i checked it from source

Comment: You can't just move those files around and expect things to work. If `index.php` is found when you put it in what you're calling your "root" folder at `http://yourdomain.com/index.php`, then that "root" folder is your public document root according to the server.  You should put Laravel up one level higher than that "root", as per my answer.